# Twitter bootstrap dropdown creates a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitters bootstrap to create a responsive site. I have a dropdown with quite a few links, when i'm in mobile view instead of making the nav collapse area bigger it creates a scrolling effect. Is there a way to make to the dropdown force the collapse nav div to increase in size or push my content down?

Here is the code i'm currently using.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <nav  id="menu1"  class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                 <div id="logo" class="pull-left hidden-md hidden-lg">
                        <div class="logo-small">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/logo-xs.png" alt="small-logo" class="img-responsive"/>


                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                                </div>
                     </div>
            </div>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
                                    'depth' => 2,
                                      'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                                     'menu_class' => 'nav nav-pills nav-justified',
                                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker() )); ?>

        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's very odd that you have your navbar in a row and a col-md-12, it doesn't go there. col-md-12 is 100% but so is nothing. So look at the examples and remove the .row and the column classes around your navbar. Unless you have css that is different from Bootstrap 3.x there is no scroll bar that occurs on a navbar without a  fixed position. http://jsbin.com/jikepu/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your css.

```
.navbar-collapse{
    max-height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you put a working example on bootply with the code that's generated from wordpress? That way I can see where it's going wrong..

Comment: Make sure that your css needs to come after bootstraps or it will be overridden. You can also try "max-height:auto !important;"